# React SwiperJs Button Outside The Container

Tags: css, reactjs

i am using react swiperjs , how do i let the button can show outside the container with css?

[JS File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aaBv2.png)

[Swiper CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6exly.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add that CSS then your left and the right button will be outside of the block

```
.swiper-button-prev{ // use sass
    .swiper-button-prev{
       left: 0px;// fit px as your demand
    }
    .swiper-button-next{
      right:0px;// 
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, but the button cant show outside the container

Answer (score 0):

have you tried giving negative values to "left" and "right"?

something like `left: -10%;`

Comment: yes, but the button cant show outside the container

Comment: maybe the container overflow is hidden. try checking the Elements tab, select the left or right button and see where they are located